# Laravel API Customizing associated columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an api source that I combined in related tables. I have customized the objects, but I cannot customize the associated data in it. How do I do this?

Previous Output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 3,
    "image": "https://localhost/800/400/cats/varem/?20215",
    "description": "Omnis eius corporis incidunt illo dolor et est odio. Et fuga hic id. Velit voluptas tempore quas voluptas iusto. Quia rerum quibusdam consectetur distinctio vero. Nihil et sed reiciendis sequi. Possimus facere ducimus provident est. Qui ut rerum ab ullam sequi est. In placeat nesciunt odio numquam iure.",
    "created_at": "2017-09-18T10:51:17.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-25T08:55:40.000000Z",
    "likes": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 10,
        "post_id": 1,
        "created_at": "1970-03-31T14:17:28.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-25T08:55:40.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Function:

```
public function like_show($id) {
         return Posts::selectRaw('id as post_id, user_id, image as post_image, description as post_description, created_at')
             ->with('likes')
             ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
             ->get();
    }
```

Next Output:

```
{
    "post_id": 1,
    "user_id": 3,
    "post_image": "https://localhost/800/400/cats/varem/?20215",
    "post_description": "Omnis eius corporis incidunt illo dolor et est odio. Et fuga hic id. Velit voluptas tempore quas voluptas iusto. Quia rerum quibusdam consectetur distinctio vero. Nihil et sed reiciendis sequi. Possimus facere ducimus provident est. Qui ut rerum ab ullam sequi est. In placeat nesciunt odio numquam iure.",
    "created_at": "2017-09-18T10:51:17.000000Z",
    "likes": [
      
    ]
  }
```

Output I want:

```
{
    "post_id": 1,
    "user_id": 3,
    "post_image": "https://localhost/800/400/cats/varem/?20215",
    "post_description": "Omnis eius corporis incidunt illo dolor et est odio. Et fuga hic id. Velit voluptas tempore quas voluptas iusto. Quia rerum quibusdam consectetur distinctio vero. Nihil et sed reiciendis sequi. Possimus facere ducimus provident est. Qui ut rerum ab ullam sequi est. In placeat nesciunt odio numquam iure.",
    "created_at": "2017-09-18T10:51:17.000000Z",
    "likes": [
      "like_id": 3,
      "user_id": 10,
      "post_id": 1,
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This is incomplete question, please give example of expected output.

Comment: you need add to select likes.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add it?

Comment: did you try likes.like_id or something like that? or likes.*

Comment: Yes I tried but it gives an error :(

Answer (score 0):

alihan.dev, You need to create Likes colletion and Likes api resoure and post reationship with Likes then following code will work for you :).

```
class Posts extends JsonResource {
    
    //likes is relationship 
    
     public function toArray($request) {
    
            return  [
                'group_id' => $this->group_id,
                'u_t_id' => $this->u_t_id,
                'group_by' => $this->group_by,
                'likes' =>Likes::collection($this->likes),
               
            ];
    
    }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm trying to figure out how to do it without using Json Resource.

Comment: then you need to define your likes reationship inside selectRaw .  Posts::selectRaw('id as post_id, user_id, image as post_image, description as post_description, created_at, likes.like_id,likes.user_id',likes.post_id,)